# ajax and javascript for redirecting between two pages with an intermediate page. also using C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have seen this design on the web quite often:-

There exists an initial page (say 1.aspx).

There exists a final page (say 3.aspx).

Normally to redirect via javascript:-

```
<a href="3.aspx" runat="server">go to final page..</a>
```

But I want to add an intermediate feature, which allows the client to be presented with an intermediate web form, asking for checkbox selections, before they are being redirected to the final page(3.aspx).

I want this intermediate web form to pop up, animated in the center of the screen, while the initial page (1.aspx) goes into the background...once the user has checked appropriate checkboxes and presssed submit, I want to pass this information via session key to 3.aspx and redirect.

Can anyone point me to the right direction? ajax? jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your intermediate features inside a div, which is set to "display: none;" so as to hide it until you are ready for it.

Rather than linking to the page 3.aspx when clicking on the words "go to final page..", you can use javascript to display and position the div (there are also some 3rd party products that make doing this easier) where the user can fill in their checkboxes, which are now being displayed on the screen.

Inside the div will be a button which actually does a postback, saves whatever it needs to into session, and then does a "Response.Redirect("3.aspx");", where you final page can be displayed.

Comment: so I am already using something like that to display success and error message (hidden div). 

Can you please tell me how this div will allow me to center the intermediate form and push the original page into the background?

Comment: By "push the original page into the background" do you mean making it darker/shadowed? Essentially, that's another div that covers the entire page, set at black 50% transparent (or similar), with the div I mentioned above on top of it. You may want to search for "css popup window". For example, this looks like it can help you - http://a100websolutions.in/jquery-css-popup/